# What are some good DFDL validators and editors to use?

Tags: schema, binaryfiles, dfdl

I want to work on binary files and I believe the Data Format Description Language serves as a schema for them, like XML schemas. My search results didn't seem to point to anything useful.

What are some good DFDL validators and editors to use?

Answer (score 3):

The only DFDL editor that I know of is supplied as part of the IBM Integration Bus toolkit. There is a free download for developers.